# How to Upload CSV Data into Custom Post Type Data with Metabox programmatically

Tags: custom-post-types, php, theme-development, metabox, csv

I have a Custom Post Type called `movies` which had only title enabled from post support and 3 custom field of metabax  as `box office`, `year`, and `director` like

[image]

now I have like 150 rows CSV formatted stored data whith same structure as

```
name, boxoffice,year,director
```

can you please let me know how I can load them into WP database to keep both Custom Post Type and metadat in the database using PHP

Comment: Is the idea that you want to be able to upload and process CSV files regularly, or allow others to do it, or just that you want to be handle one or a couple uploads? It may well be easier to "load them into the WP db" using WP functions acting directly on the data and producing posts and post meta (which reside in the database), than to upload the data into the the db and then extract it or re-extract it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply . This actually only one time loading data to the database and for first time( I am not getting any SQL data from existing database)

Comment: I was thinking about leaving the outlines of my own approach to this problem as an answer, but, looking for the quickest way to parse a CSV file, I ran into this post: https://www.sitepoint.com/programmatically-creating-wordpress-posts-from-csv-data/ You could probably skip much of it and just get to the use of fgetcsv() and following code, but, depending on your level of coding knowledge, you might actually find it easier to install the entire thing even for one-time use.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $rows = array();
        if($_FILES['file']['name'])
        {
            $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
            if($filename[1] == 'csv')
            {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");   
                $count=0;
                while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                {
                     query_posts(array( 
                            'post_type' => 'custom-post-type',
                        ) ); 
                    while(have_posts()) : the_post();
                    $post_id->ID;
                    $rows[] = array(
                        'variable1' =>  $data[1] . "," . $data[2] . "," . $data[3] . "," . $data[4],
//above line for using multiple cells of csv file to a single variable
                        'variable2'   =>  $data[5],
                        'variable3'  => $data[6],
                        'variable4'                 => $data[7],
                        'variable5'                 => $data[8],
                        'variable6'         => $data[9]
                    );
                endwhile; 
                    $count++;
                }
                foreach($rows as $row => $rowValue  ){
                    add_row('rates', $rowValue, $post_id);  
                }   
                fclose($handle);
            }
        }
    }
```